# Inconsistency when cbind tibble and matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

Unfortunately, I have spotted a weird inconsistency in the colnames when `cbind` different 2 particular objects: `tibbles` that has been `by_group()`ed and `matrix`. I writing this here because I would understand what is going on under the hood with the `cbind` operation and these 2 objects.

Consider the following objects:

#### Simple tibble

```
library(tidyverse)

tbl <- tibble(tbl_name = seq(1,8))
# # A tibble: 8 x 1
# tbl_name
# <int>
# 1        1
# 2        2
# 3        3
# 4        4
# 5        5
# 6        6
# 7        7
# 8        8
```

#### Simple data.frame

```
df <- data.frame(df_name = seq(1,8))
df 

# df_name
# 1       1
# 2       2
# 3       3
# 4       4
# 5       5
# 6       6
# 7       7
# 8       8
```

#### Simple `matrix`

```
mtx <- matrix(seq(1,8), nrow = 8)
colnames(mtx) <- "mtx_name"

# mtx_name
# [1,]        1
# [2,]        2
# [3,]        3
# [4,]        4
# [5,]        5
# [6,]        6
# [7,]        7
# [8,]        8
```

#### `by_group`ed `tibble`

```
tb2 <- tibble(tbl2_name = seq(1,8),
              tbl_group_by = c("a","b","b","c","d","d","d","d"))

tb2 <- tb2 %>%
  group_by(tbl_group_by) %>%
  mutate(N_by_group = n()) 
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   tbl_group_by [4]
# tbl2_name tbl_group_by N_by_group
# <int> <chr>             <int>
# 1         1 a                     1
# 2         2 b                     2
# 3         3 b                     2
# 4         4 c                     1
# 5         5 d                     4
# 6         6 d                     4
# 7         7 d                     4
# 8         8 d                     4
```

### When `cbind` them:

#### >This works (a.k.a: keeps the correct names)

```
# Comparison 

# tibble & data.frame: OK
cbind(tbl,df)
# tbl_name df_name
# 1        1       1
# 2        2       2
# 3        3       3
# 4        4       4
# 5        5       5
# 6        6       6
# 7        7       7
# 8        8       8


# matrix & data.frame: OK
cbind(mtx,df)

# mtx_name df_name
# 1        1       1
# 2        2       2
# 3        3       3
# 4        4       4
# 5        5       5
# 6        6       6
# 7        7       7
# 8        8       8

# tibble & matrix: OK
cbind(tbl,mtx)

# tbl_name mtx_name
# 1        1        1
# 2        2        2
# 3        3        3
# 4        4        4
# 5        5        5
# 6        6        6
# 7        7        7
# 8        8        8
```

#### This *doesn't* work (a.k.a: destroyed the colname of the `matrix`)

```
# tibble(group_by()) & matrix: oops!!!!
cbind(tb2,mtx)

# New names:
#   * NA -> ...4
# # A tibble: 8 x 4
# # Groups:   tbl_group_by [4]
# tbl2_name tbl_group_by N_by_group ...4[,"mtx_name"]
# <int> <chr>             <int>             <int>
# 1         1 a                     1                 1
# 2         2 b                     2                 2
# 3         3 b                     2                 3
# 4         4 c                     1                 4
# 5         5 d                     4                 5
# 6         6 d                     4                 6
# 7         7 d                     4                 7
# 8         8 d                     4                 8
```

Any intuition of what's happening or how to prevent it, is very welcome. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can remove the group attributes with `ungroup` and now `cbind` should work

```
library(dplyr)
cbind(ungroup(tb2), mtx)
```

-output

```
#    tbl2_name tbl_group_by N_by_group mtx_name
#1         1            a          1        1
#2         2            b          2        2
#3         3            b          2        3
#4         4            c          1        4
#5         5            d          4        5
#6         6            d          4        6
#7         7            d          4        7
#8         8            d          4        8
```

---

Or specifically use `cbind.data.frame` because by default it may use `cbind.matrix`

```
cbind.data.frame(tb2, mtx)
```

---

When we create the 'tb2', after grouping, make sure to `ungroup` to prevent this kind of issues

```
tb2 <- tb2 %>%
         group_by(tbl_group_by) %>%
         mutate(N_by_group = n())  %>%
         ungroup
```

---

Or make use of `is_grouped_df` to find if the data is grouped or not and then `ungroup`

```
f1 <- function(dat) {
       if(dplyr::is_grouped_df(dat)) {
        dat <- ungroup(dat)
       }
       dat
   }

cbind(f1(tb2), mtx)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @akrun. Indeed `ungroup` solves the problem, but... is it possible to `ungroup`ed the `tibble` when created? Because, probably it is better this, instead of start guessing which of my tibbles comes `group`ed, isn't it?

Comment: @ÁlvaroA.GutiérrezVargas you could convert all tibbles to data.frame with `as.data.frame` so that it removes the group attributes or have `ungroup` at the end of pipe whenever there is a group_by operation.  Updated the post

Comment: Thank you @akrun!!! That was **exactly**  was I was searching for.